# Total time within series of date/time ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a systems guy, so code isn't really my forte. I'm building a new front-end for our in-house ticketing system. I pull the tickets from the database as objects and iterate over them. I have it set up so that each ticket object has an "updates" property which is an array of objects describing each time it was interacted with. I use the type of interaction to determine if the timer should be effected, and if so, if it should be started or stopped.

```
User creates a ticket -> timer starts
Tech1 responds to the ticket asking for more information -> timer stops
User responds -> timer starts again
Tech1 escalates ticket to tech2 -> no change in timer status
Tech2 resolves issue and closes ticket -> timer stops
```

I've been able to get it to work with a single start/stop event (open/close, nothing in-between) per ticket, including subtracting non-business hours (nights, weekends, and holidays), but I'm having trouble coming up with a clean way to deal with multiple start/stops per ticket.

The main thing throwing a wrench in things is validating the input. For example, a user might submit a response (triggering a start event), then realize they forgot to add something and submit a second response (triggering another start event) before a tech responds.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on how to go about this or about what I can do to improve my existing code, I'm sure it is far less than optimal.

Here is an example of a ticket object:

```
{
    "status":"closed",
    "id":13137,
    "importance":4,
    "type":1,
    "owner":"User1",
    "category":"User Accounts",
    "cc":[
        "User2",
        "User3"
    ],
    "updates":[
        {
            "time":1393264332000,
            "updator":"Tech1",
            "event":"techClose",
            "detail":"Done. Let us know if you need anything else."
        },
        {
            "time":1393261496000,
            "updator":"Tech2",
            "event":"assigned",
            "detail":"Tech1"
        },
        {
            "time":1393030776000,
            "updator":"User1",
            "event":"clientReply",
            "detail":"Actually, nevermind, just remove them from the groups."
        },
        {
            "time":1393030632000,
            "updator":"User1",
            "event":"clientReply",
            "detail":"Can you give me a list and I'll let ya know what to do with each?"
        },
        {
            "time":1393002994000,
            "updator":"Tech2",
            "event":"techResponse",
            "detail":"These accounts are disabled, they are still in the lists because the accounts still exist, but they are not able to be logged in to or accessed in any other way. It is standard practice to leave the accounts exactly as they were, but in a disabled state just in case you need to access them at a later date because any other changes cannot be reversed. If you'd prefer, we can remove them from the groups associated with those distribution lists or delete the accounts entirely."
        },
        {
            "time":1392991707000,
            "updator":"User1",
            "event":"userCreate",
            "detail":"Hey. Can you revise the All employee and other staff email groups to delete the people that are no longer here? Thx."
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is how the above might be represented when passed into the function:

```
start = [1392991707000,1393030632000,1393030776000];
stop = [1393002994000,1393264332000];
```

And here is the function I am currently using (I'm not passing in arrays, just single ints at the moment):

```
    function timeCalc(start, end){
// Array of non-working days (eg: weekends) in numerical weekday format starting with Sunday=0 and ending with Saturday=6
    var daysOff = new Array(0,6);
// Array of non-working dates (eg: holidays) in any valid date format, such as: "October 13, 1975" or "75,10,13"
    var holidays = new Array("2014,02,17","2014,05,26","2014,07,04","2014,08,01","2014,11,11","2014,11,27","2014,11,28","2014,12,25");
// Two arrays defining business hours in 24hour time. busHoursStart contains all starting times, busHoursEnd contains all ending times. So if you work 9-5 with a lunch break from 12-1, put "9,13" in start and "12,17" in end.
    /*var busHoursStart = new Array("9");
    var busHoursEnd = new Array("17");*/
// Just using start and end time, no array for now
    var busHoursStart = 9;
    var busHoursEnd = 17;
// Define other variables (no need to configure)
    var datesBetween = new Array();
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    var busHoursPerDay = (busHoursEnd - busHoursStart);
    var subtractDays = 0;

// Create array of JS timestamps (UNIX time in milliseconds) representing each full day between the start and end dates (including the end date)
    var dateDiff = Math.round(Math.abs(start.getTime() - end.getTime())/(oneDay));
    for (var i=0; i<dateDiff; i++){
        datesBetween.push(new Date(start.getTime()+(i*oneDay)));
    }

// Remove days off
    var noWeekends=$.grep(datesBetween, function(wDate){
        var wFail;
        $.each(daysOff,function(wKey,wVal){
            if(wDate.getDay() == wVal) wFail=wDate;
        });
        return (wDate != wFail);
    }); 

// Remove holidays
    var noHolidays=$.grep(noWeekends, function(hDate){
        var hFail;
        $.each(holidays,function(hKey,hVal){
            if(hDate.toDateString() == new Date(hVal).toDateString()) hFail=hDate;
        });
        return (hDate != hFail);
    });

    var days=(noHolidays.length - 1);

// This should be made into a function
// If start event is before business hours, set start time to when business hours start
    if(start.getHours() < busHoursStart){
        var startTime = busHoursStart;
    }
// If start event is after business hours, set start time to when the next day's business hours start by adding a day to the counter
    else if(start.getHours() >= busHoursEnd){
        var startTime = busHoursStart;
        subtractDays++;
    }
    else var startTime = start.getHours();

// If end is before business hours, set end time to when business hours start
    if(end.getHours() < busHoursStart){
        var endTime = busHoursStart;
    }
// If end is after business hours, set end time to to when the next day's business hours start by adding a day to the counter
    else if(end.getHours() >= busHoursEnd){
        var endTime = busHoursStart;
        subtractDays++;
    }
    else var endTime = end.getHours();

// If the end time is a later hour than the start time, add up hours from full days then add hours between start and end
    if(endTime >= startTime){
        var hours = (days - subtractDays) * busHoursPerDay) + (endTime - startTime);
    }
// If the end time is an earlier hour than the start time, add up hours from full days then get hours between start and close time and hours between open time and end time, add them together and subtract a full day worth of time
    else {
        var hours = ((days - subtractDays) * busHoursPerDay) + ((busHoursEnd - startTime) + (endTime - busHoursStart));
    }

    console.log("Days: "+days+" Hours: "+hours);
    return hours;
}
```